# Steam crashes on run

Tags: steam

Alright so this is rather odd, for some reason whenever I run Steam it gets to the update pop-up then crashes. I'm running 12.04 32bit on my Dell Latitude ATG D620 and what I find odd is on my PC I built (Running 12.04 64bit) I have no problems running steam at all.

When I ran steam in terminal this is what I got.

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
[0413/095724:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/../common/steamservice.cpp (50) : Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL
Assert( Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL ):/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/../common/steamservice.cpp:50

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140413095724_11.dmp
No minidump written, nothing to upload.
/home/dxnfbkjdfk/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755:  3082 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-a7850f30-e313-4120-b1f3-ac8bf2140413
```

I ran it again after I deleted the appcache and I got this.

```
$ rm -Rf ~/.steam/steam/appcache
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
[0413/100856:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/../common/steamservice.cpp (50) : Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL
Assert( Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL ):/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/../common/steamservice.cpp:50

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140413100854_1.dmp
/home/dxnfbkjdfk/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755:  3401 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-f71bef38-7f2a-4140-a3ad-ff04d2140413
```

Any insight would be helpful

So I ran it again through terminal, worked for a moment and then crashed again. this is what I got

```
(steam:3262): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)
ExecCommandLine: "/home/dxnfbkjdfk/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://open/driverhelperready"
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/driverhelperready"
Generating new string page texture 93: 1024x256, total string texture memory is 2.29 MB
CAPIJobRequestUserStats - Server response failed 2
Generating new string page texture 108: 128x256, total string texture memory is 2.42 MB
Generating new string page texture 114: 512x256, total string texture memory is 2.95 MB
Generating new string page texture 115: 128x256, total string texture memory is 3.08 MB
Generating new string page texture 119: 2048x256, total string texture memory is 5.18 MB
Generating new string page texture 122: 256x256, total string texture memory is 5.44 MB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
OnFocusWindowChanged to window type: k_EWindowTypeNonSteamDesktop, 0
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error
[2014-04-17 10:34:25] Startup - updater built Feb 25 2014 13:44:43
[2014-04-17 10:34:25] Verifying installation...
[2014-04-17 10:34:25] Verification complete
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/../common/steamservice.cpp (50) : Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL
Assert( Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL ):/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/../common/steamservice.cpp:50

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1393366296_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140417103425_1.dmp
/home/dxnfbkjdfk/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755:  3262 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-8ac5537f-e364-4b4a-8854-70bce2140417
```